# How do I create a custom WordPress page?

Tags: wordpress

I want my WordPress blog to have a page called music. On that page I will query the DB for posts with the category music and then change around the look and feel of the posts.  So I can't just put a link to `/categories/music/` because I want to do custom work on the posts.

Should I put this code in a separate php file and link to it? I think I may lose access to all the nice WordPress API calls if I do that.

I was thinking about using a filter, but I am not sure which one to use.  I was thinking something like the following except `the_title` has not been grabbed yet so I cannot check the title.

```
function show_music(){

    if( is_page() && the_title('','',false) == 'music' ){
        echo "got here";
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'show_portfolio');
```

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the below code in the file, and then put the file in the Theme folder. Then you can create a page using Wordpress pages and select a page template with the name you put in this comment:

```
/*
Template Name: Something Goes Here
*/
```

Comment: sweet...just out of curiosity.  i may want to implement this as a plugin.  then would i have to use a filter? if so, do you know which?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I haven't seen many plugins that create there own pages outside of the WP-admin area, so not really sure.

Comment: to make your own page you can just use `wp_insert_post`, if you do a quick search for wp_insert_post page type you'll likely find something

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom page within your theme. If you dont have idea how to create custme page or template page in WordPress theme then view my easy tutorial [How to create template page in WordPress](http://abdul.thinkbeyondwindow.com/blog/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-create-wordpress-theme-template-page/)